# How to set a time limit for a variable in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timeout

I want to set the time limit for a value in mysql database.

When the values is `modified`, I want to make it to `null` after `10 min` from the time when it's value was set.

How ca I do it?

Comment: ?? Php is a script language.  It executes once through and thats that.  Theres is no "memory" after execution.   Unless you're talking about storing a variable in a session?  But my guess is you don't fully understand what you're asking.

Comment: I think it would be enough to just set an expiration time along with the value in Mysql, then the next time that record is accessed you check if it's expired and then decide (in PHP) if it's the stored value or null.  The only way I can think to set it to null after 10 minutes is with a CRON job that inspects that table every few minutes, in which case you still need an expiration time. And that could impact performance, and be basically redundant.

Comment: Its kind of like if a tree falls in the woods and no one is there to hear it.  If a value in the DB expires and no one is there to check it, does it matter if it's "actually" null, it only matter the next time someone does something with it.

Comment: As @ArtisticPhoenix suggested - you can nullify columns just BEFORE any script access this column.

Comment: Why not just have an extra column in your db to store the entry's creation time and add some logic to your script to compare the current time against that and either use or delete it depending on the result?

Comment: Please see [ask]. What do you want to do do, what have you tried, and what results did you get.

Comment: General content clear